# What are these blocked sections in java GUI

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

Java noob here.

I am taking an intro to java class. The professor wants me to create a gui that looks like this:

[image: Pizza GUI]

But I have no idea what those blocked sections are (labeled Pizza Size, and Toppings).

I just need to know what they are called so I can look up some documentation on them. Prof is horribly unorganized, so of course no mention in the notes. Also having a tough time figuring out what they are by Google search due to not having the right keyword.

I just need the name of those sections, then I can find documentation for how to create them.

Comment: Those are [`JPanel`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JPanel.html)(s) (*a generic lightweight container*). Here is a tutorial on [How to Use Panels](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/panel.html).

Comment: They are, as has been mentioned, `JPanel`s, which are using a `TitledBorder` - You can see [How to Use Borders](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/border.html) for some more details

Answer (score 4):

These are [`TitledBorder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/border/TitledBorder.html)s (a class implementing the `Border` interface.

You can put a `Border` around any `JComponent`.
In your example screenshot there are 2 `JPanel`s, each with a `TitledBorder`.

See the tutorial [How to Use Borders](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/border.html) for more info.